# Dynamic Dropdown, JQuery, Not Submitting form with Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following code, which creates a dynamic dropdown (`Text Color`) based on the selection of another dropdown (`Background Color`)

It works as expected, and populates the Text Color dropdown perfectly.

However, when I submit my form, the value for `textC` is blank everytime. If I create a simple select for `Text Color`, my form submits fine, and all variables are available on the next page via POST.

Any thoughts to why the the `textC` value is always blank with this code?

```js
var black = [
{display: "Gray", value: "gray" }, 
{display: "Warm Red", value: "red" }, 
{display: "White", value: "white" }];

var white = [
{display: "Black", value: "black" }, 
{display: "Gray", value: "gray" }, 
{display: "Warm Red", value: "red" }];

var gray = [
{display: "Black", value: "black" }, 
{display: "Warm Red", value: "red" }, 
{display: "White", value: "white" }];

$("#parent_selection").change(function() {
    var parent = $(this).val(); //get option value from parent 
    
    switch(parent){ //using switch compare selected option and populate child
          case 'black':
            list(black);
            break;
          case 'white':
            list(white);
            break;              
          case 'gray':
            list(gray);
            break;  
          default: //default child option is blank
            $("#textC").html('');  
            break;
       }
});

//function to populate child select box
function list(array_list)
    {
    $("#textC").html(""); //reset child options
    $(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options 
        $("#textC").append("<option value=''+array_list[i].value+''>"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
    });
}
```

```html
<p><b>Background Color ?</b><br>
<select name="theme" id="parent_selection">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="gray">Gray</option>
</select>

<p><b>Text Color?</b><br>   
<select name="textC" id="textC">
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this instead:

```
//function to populate child select box
function list(array_list)
{
    $("#textC").html(""); //reset child options
    $(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options 
        $('<option>').val(array_list[i].value).text(array_list[i].display).appendTo('#textC');
    });
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Anokrize/t1w1k463/

Comment: when I try this, the dynamic dropdown does not populate at all when I select something in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

you can have other option by using `select2` https://select2.github.io/

```js
//set each item to id=value, text=display
var black = [
{text:"", id:""},
{text: "Gray", id: "gray" }, 
{text: "Warm Red", id: "red" }, 
{text: "White", id: "white" }];

//initialized select2 control.
$("#textC").select2({
    data: black,
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1, 
    placeholder: "choose item",
    selectOnClose: true,
    closeOnSelect: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="textC" name="textC" style="width:100%"></select>
```

Comment: yup, very handy, you can also set the `data` values from an `ajax` json result.